# DataBinding to listbox

Tags: c#, json, data-binding

The "a.text" is extracted from my JSON Response. I am trying to display the "a.text" in the listbox.

```
List<Feature> features = App.dResult.directions[0].features;
        foreach (Feature f in features)
        {
            Attributes a = f.attributes;
            MessageBox.Show(a.text);
            directionListBox.ItemsSource = a.text;

        }
```

I tried using binding the "a.text" to the listbox but there is no display.

```
<ListBox x:Name="directionListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding a.text}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding a.text}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Can anyone provide me with some idea on how to bind the "a.text" to listbox?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsSource Property of a ListBox should not point to a String, like a.text, but to an ObservableCollection.

Try something like this:

1st: derive that code class from INotifyPropertyChanged.

2nd: You can get the ObservableList from [here](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/132415f7-a33a-40bc-b3e0-57af0b498f7b.aspx) or use ObservableCollection instead.

3rd: Then use this code (untested, but might work):

```
ObservableList<String> featList = new ObservableCollection<String>();
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void InvokePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
public ObservableList<String> FeatList
{
    get { return featList; }
    set
    {
        featList = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged("FeatList");
    }
}
List<Feature> features = App.dResult.directions[0].features;
foreach (Feature f in features)
{
    Attributes a = f.attributes;
    //MessageBox.Show(a.text);
    FeatList.add(a.text);
}
```

4th: At the top of the fild you have to use a 'using' statement to import the ObservableList.

Then, bind the listbox'es ItemSource to this list, and make the TextBlock's Binding just bind to the default DataContext, which will be the string from the list:

```
<ListBox x:Name="directionListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FeatList}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: where can i apply the codes? I'm not very sure about ObservableCollection.

Comment: Just put the code from the link to the ObservableList into a file, put it in your project. The rest of the above you should put directly in your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But i think you misunderstood my question. The "a.text" is not to convert to string. I wish to bind "a.text" into the observableCollection.

P.S the "a.text" is the extracted string from my JSON response

Comment: Well this is exactly what the solution I proposed does. Did you try it? (including the XAML?)

Comment: Did you do what I wrote above under 2nd and 4th? Did you read the whole answer or did you just paste the code? ;-) If there's an error still, what is it?

Comment: Look at the top of your c# file. There are some using statements for importing namespaces. There import the namespace for the list you downloaded and put into your project under the 2nd step. Such basic things can also easily be found out via Google.

Comment: i did all the steps accordingly. But shouldn't the foreach be in the method? the error : invalid token 'foreach' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Man, of course it must be in a method! I copied that from your question, I guess you would know where your code comes from. Please don't ask any more questions that can be answered by a C# beginners tutorial.

Comment: I've tried all but the "featList" in "public ObservableList<String> FeatList" has error: inconsistent accessibility.

Comment: As I said, please Google the basic programming knowledge questions you might lack. If you can't work around this simple problem yourself (that you don't only have in C#/.NET, but also in other programming languages), you should better stop creating an application at all. Sorry man, but these are my last characters typed in this answer.